Using flow custom error to restrict users from deleting opp team members
I created a flow on OpportunityTeamMember object which triggers when a record is being deleted.
Initial condition to trigger the flow is : Opportunity_Stage__c equals Closed. This a custom formula field I created to fetch the opportunity stage name.
I then used a decision to check if the user profile is other than system admin. If yes, in that case a custom error should be thrown:
"Please submit a Salesforce Case to delete the Team Member on a Closed Opportunity."
When I test this, I do get an error, but that is a salesforce standard error and not the custom error that I desire.
Error that I received:
An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1080960640-923241 (-693052815)



It doesn't look like you defined the error message in the Custom Error component per your screen shot

Custom error message is mentioned in the Error Message box

ah, sorry -- I misread
